# In .NET, what is the best way to resolve this necessary circular dependency using injection?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

Here are my three class examples.  There are dozens of these Adapters, one for each entity in my dataset, and they handle all the conversions between different protocols for that entity.  Works great until I want hydrated objects.  In this example, a client may have an Agent assigned to them.  An Agent may be a user in our system and thus have a User object. A User may be a ClientUser and thus may have a Client assigned to them. These things aren't cyclical in Data but their types a

ClientAdapter.cs

```cs
public interface IClientAdapter :
    IModelAdapter<ClientModel, ClientDatabaseModel, ClientResponseModel>
{
}

public class ClientAdapter : IClientAdapter
{ 
    IAgentAdapter _agentAdapter;

    public ClientAdapter(IAgentAdapter agentAdapter)
    {
        _agentAdapter = agentAdapter; 
    }

    public ClientResponseModel convertFromModelToResponseModel(ClientModel model)
    {
        ClientResponseModel responseModel = new ClientResponseModel()
        {
            Id = model.Id, 
            AgentId = model.AgentId,
            Agent = model.Agent == null
                ? null
                : this._agentAdapter.convertFromModelToResponseModel(model.Agent), 
            Name = model.Name
        };
 
        return responseModel;
    }
}
```

AgentAdapter.cs

```cs
public interface IAgentAdapter :
    IModelAdapter<AgentModel, AgentDatabaseModel, AgentResponseModel>
{
}

public class AgentAdapter : IAgentAdapter
{ 
    IUserAdapter _userAdapter;

    public AgentAdapter(IUserAdapter userAdapter)
    {
        _userAdapter = userAdapter; 
    }

    public AgentResponseModel convertFromModelToResponseModel(AgentModel model)
    {
        AgentResponseModel responseModel = new AgentResponseModel()
        {
            Id = model.Id, 
            UserId = model.UserId,
            User = model.User == null
                ? null
                : this._userAdapter.convertFromModelToResponseModel(model.User), 
            Name = model.Name
        };
 
        return responseModel;
    }
}
```

UserAdapter.cs

```cs
public interface IUserAdapter :
    IModelAdapter<UserModel, UserDatabaseModel, UserResponseModel> 
{
}

public class UserAdapter : IUserAdapter
{ 
    IClientAdapter _clientAdapter;

    public UserAdapter(IClientAdapter clientAdapter)
    {
        _clientAdapter = clientAdapter; 
    }

    public UserResponseModel convertFromModelToResponseModel(UserModel model)
    {
        UserResponseModel responseModel = new UserResponseModel()
        {
            Id = model.Id, 
            ClientId = model.ClientId,
            Client = model.UserClient == null
               ? null
               : this._clientAdapter.convertFromModelToResponseModel(model.Client), 
            Name = model.Name
        };
 
        return responseModel;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the classes do, by necessity, call each other.  There's no concern of a loop because the only way they can have non-null values is by explicit request so really the main issue is that the builder is complaining about the injection circular reference and there's likely a change at the injection level that is needed and I don't understand/know .NET's injection well enough to fix it.

Here is my injection surrounding these three classes, very simple:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// add services to DI container
{
    var services = builder.Services;

    services.AddScoped<IAgentAdapter, AgentAdapter>();
    services.AddScoped<IClientAdapter, ClientAdapter>();
    services.AddScoped<IUserAdapter, UserAdapter>();
}

var app = builder.Build();
```

This accomplishes the system using my definitions by default and also lets me unit test by overriding my implementations at will, but also is the source of the runtime error about circular dependency.   Sup?

Comment: That's a lot of repetitive code based on types. Use an interface that all adapters share (ie: IAdapter) and inherit from that. You could even create an abstract base class for overriding. You may be able to simply use AutoMapper...

Comment: These classes aren't really repetitive, it's just stripped down for an example.

What you're suggesting would lead to a single interface and partial classes covering hundreds of functions.  I want to avoid that but I'm ok doing it if it's really the most transparent way to do it (it might be)

Comment: Can you explain again why you think at runtime there will be no loop?

Answer (score 2):

If the circular dependencies cannot be removed, one approach is to inject `Lazy<T>` instead. If that wont work, you could inject the `IServiceProvider` and resolve the dependent type explicitly. Using `IServiceProvider` can be considered an anti-pattern and I would only use it as a last resort. If you do use it, be sure add a comment so the next developer (Jr?) doesn't think that this is the approach that should be used everywhere.

Comment: How would I use Lazy<T> to solve this, though?  Searching if .NET's DI supports Lazy loading (already did look that up) doesn't really yield a lot of positive results that don't use provider patterns or feel unstable.  If I only inject Lazy<T> it throws errors as one would expect, but is there something I'm missing in my injection setup that would make it "just work"?

Comment: It should just work. Autofac already knows how to resolve `Lazy<IAgentAdapter>`. At least that is what I remember.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to refactor the code to remove the circular dependency, but if it is unavoidable you could use Lazy<> to declare the dependency. Autofac [supports](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) that OTB. If your container has no support, you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45775657/2982757) for a way to implement this feature easily.

Comment: There IS a clean refactor: put all adapters (hundreds) in one assembly and then use partial classes for cleanliness.  It's not great but honestly that's what the framework probably really wants here.

I am not using Autofac but could consider it.  It's a big change for my timeline but it supporting lazy loading is nice. 

I'm reading the non-Autofac answer now, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @kamii, check the linked post for an implementation of a Lazy injector that will probably suit you. On how to use Lazy for injection check the linked autofac doc at the section "Delayed Instantiation", it would be the same scenario.

Comment: I'm trying it out but there are lots of resolution errors in non-lazy classes that are injecting lazy dependencies.  Does the entire tree have to be lazy loaded for the Lazier/Lazy solution to work?

Comment: I can't tell.... I have a test project with the Lazier class from the linked article and works like a charm. Circular references work ok using lazy, and the remaining dependencies work as usual. You don't need the entire tree to be lazy. Simply, A requires B and B requires Lazy<A>, don't use the Value of a lazy reference in the constructor, of course.

Comment: If you go for this lazy-loading solution, consider hiding lazy-loading behind an abstraction instead of letting consumers depend directly on `Lazy<T>`. For instance, you can create a `LazyUserAdapter : IUserAdapter` implementation that depends on `Lazy<IUserAdapter>`. By registering this class as `IUserAdapter` you will be able to break the cycle without having to change any of the code and without leaking implementation details (`Lazy<T>` is an implementation detail) into consumers.